# Matrix A find k -the number of positive elements

Tags: c++

Enter the matrix A(NxM), output it. In each row of the matrix, find k -the number of positive elements. In the rows, all the elements after the kth are increased by the sum of the positive elements of this row. What's wrong with the program? The program incorrectly outputs the elements of the modified array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); 
int n, m;
cout << "Введите количество строк: ";
cin >> n;
cout << "Введите количество столбцов: ";
cin >> m;
int A[10][10];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            cout<<"\nA["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]=";
            cin>>A[i][j];
    }
 
cout << "\nМассив A:"; 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout<<"\n";
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    cout<<"\t"<<A[i][j];
}
cout<<endl;
int k;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    k=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
            if(A[i][j]>0) 
            k++;
}
 
int sum;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    sum=0;
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            if (A[i][j]>0)
                sum+=A[i][j];
}
 
for (int i = k; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        A[i][j] = A[i][j] + sum;
 
 
cout << "Измененный массив A:";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            cout << "\t" << A[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you can condense 2 for loops (k and sum) into 1.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate `k` for each row, but after the loop `k` will only store the value of the last row. You need to store `k` for each row. Then in the loop:

```
for (int i = k; i < n; i++)
```

you skip the first `k-1` rows, but you should add the sum in each row.

Change the last part of the code to:

```
int k;
std::vector<int> ks;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    k=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
            if(A[i][j]>0) 
            k++;
    ks.push_back(k);
}
 
int sum;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    sum=0;
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            if (A[i][j]>0)
                sum+=A[i][j];
}
 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = ks[i]; j < m; j++)
        A[i][j] = A[i][j] + sum;
```

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to do it easier without a vector?

Comment: @MoshTumuch if you know the max number of rows you can use a fixed size array